# Merge eventbrite api response with wordpress CPT

Tags: php, wordpress, api, eventbrite

I am trying to figure out the best way to do this.

I need to get event list from eventbrite and display them on my wordpress page. This is working good trough the Eventbrite php class api.

But now i need to have the ability to create events using a custom post type in my wordpress. With no connection to Eventbrite just a post with some date field and such.

My problem is: How can i merge the eventbrite response with a wordpress custom post type query to sort them by date ? Is this even possible and have anyone done it ?

Please point me in the right direction if you got an idea on how to accomplish this!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to approach this, but I think the cleanest would be something like this:

- Get events from each source using their own API.
- Process each type of event for display and load the results into an `$all_events[$event_datetime] = $event_string` array. You'll want a separate function for each event type.
- Then `ksort($all_events)` to generate the sorted display list, and loop through it to generate the output.

Good luck.